# How to find out the SoftPhone Layout Settings

Tags: apex, javascript, webservices, opencti, softphone

I understand that SoftPhone Layouts are related to Open CTI and its all exposed through Open CTI methods. I'm just wondering if the softphone layout(equivalent to getSoftphoneLayout method) can be accessed through code?

I understand that we can use Metadata API to retrieve them but I'm looking for a possibility to access via APEX or JavaScript(other than OpenCTI methods).

I'm doing this for a temporary workaround and looking out for options!

Thanks in Advance! Peace!

Comment: This is an old question, but I have the same requirements. I haven't found any way to do it in Apex. Have you been able to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: @mkorman I made a workaround by hitting the url "/_ui/cti/callcenter/CallCenterSettingsServlet" from JS(GET call) to get the data. Not a perfect solution, but a working one.