# Finding SoftPhone Layouts via Apex

Tags: apex, cti

I would like to programmatically access the **SoftPhone Layouts** present in an organisation via Apex. In particular, I want to know whether one exists.

I know this information is available via [the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_describesoftphonelayout.htm) but I haven't found a similar method in Apex.

I have found [an old question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126537/how-to-find-out-the-softphone-layout-settings) asking the for the same information, but it has no answers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SF's Classic or Lightning Open CTI interface it has a Javascript method to retrieve the softphone layout.

The method is:

CLASSIC:   sforce.interaction.cti.getSoftphoneLayout
LIGHTNING: sforce.opencti.getSoftphoneLayout